# MySQL: why provide size of a datatype in table definition?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.1

Below is an example table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mytable` (
      `id` MEDIUMINT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `content` text NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `date_added` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00',
      `date_modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00',
      `published` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

For example: as per [MySQL datatype tutorial](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/integer-types.html)  MEDIUMINT has 3 Bytes storage and can contains value from `-8388608` to `8388607`.

- Then why should write `Mediumint(5), tinyint(1), int(11) etc...` in
  table definition?
- What is the impact of defining size of datatype in
  table definition?
- Is there any affect of defining size on memory acquisition?
- If we don't define size of datatype, it automatically define the size. So, isn't it better to not define the size?

My question is not limited to Mediumint and int datatype. It is for all numeric datatypes which MySQL support.Please provide your suggestions as per the concern I raised.

Comment: It's the display width. See this previous question http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55059/what-is-the-meaning-of-tinyintn/55060#55060

Comment: It's only for the display of the width of this column.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634104/what-is-the-size-of-column-of-int11-in-mysql-in-bytes][1]
 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634104/what-is-the-size-of-column-of-int11-in-mysql-in-bytes

Comment: the manual you are referencing to gives an explanation as well: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-type-attributes.html

Comment: I have update my question a little bit...

Comment: Hints for display.

Comment: What does you mean by display width?